# Is there any difference between Assets -> Create Sprite and GameObject -> Create 2D Sprite Object

Tags: unity-game-engine, ide

I am developing 2D game using Unity 2018. As I understand there are at least two ways of creating sprites using upper menu in Unity.

1. GameObject -> 2D Object -> Sprite
   [image]
2. Assets -> Create -> Sprites -> Square/Triangle/etc.
   [image]

Questions:

1. Is there any difference between these two approaches of creating sprite objects. Which one should I prefer according to best practices.
2. If there is no difference then there must be explanation why these two menus exist.

Comment: GameObject menu creates a GameObject and attaches the SpriteRenderer to it. The Asset menu generate an asset based on the choice you want such as triangle, hexagon and more. To create such shape in the GameObject menu, you would have to import your own triangle, hexagon images. The Asset menu will generate these for you. Asset  menu is used to generate complex 2D shapes when you don't have the files. That's really it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're two completely different things.

When you create a sprite `Asset`, you create a physical file in the Assets folder which contains the graphic data of that sprite, and that sprite asset can be referenced by any `Sprite Renderer` component in any scene.

When you create a sprite `GameObject`, you create a scene-specific game object with a `Sprite Renderer` attached to it, so that Unity can (at the least) be able to render it on screen (of course, you can do a lot more with it, attach to it a collider, scripts for its behaviour, etc.). Moreover, if you notice, the `Sprite Renderer` component of the game object has the `Sprite` property empty, and in that property you reference a "physical" `Sprite` asset (the actual graphic data of the sprite) to render.

The only thing that's similar is when you drag and drop a `Sprite` asset to the hierarchy, in that case Unity will create for you a sprite game object, with already the sprite property of the `Sprite Renderer` referencing the sprite asset you dragged, whereas when you create a sprite game object, you still need to drag the `Sprite` asset to the sprite field of the renderer.

Comment: Thanks @Programmer and Galandil, you both helped me to understand the difference. Cool!